# TFS Merge with Disgard Changeset Produces a Different Source File List than the Changeset

Tags: merge

I am working with tfs 2012.

I have a *huge* changeset that has already been merged up from Main -> Stable. I now need to merge some changes down from Stable -> Main, and I want to disregard this changeset. However, when I run my command from the command line and the "Check In - Source Files" window pops up, it is clear that the source files it thinks need to be merged *do not reflect the files in the changeset I'm trying to disregard* (see attached screen shots). I've never run in to this and am a little perplexed; I've see questions that deal with merge/discard issues, but these mostly have to do with other issues, like dealing with Partial Updates and such. Anyone run in to this before?

```
tf merge $/Project/Stable $/Project/Main /discard /recursive /version:C1234~C1234
```

[image: "Check In - Source Files" window]
[image: Changeset Details]

Answer (score 0):

We need to record merge history that the changeset has been merged. Did you these pending edits already in your workspace? If they had come from a merge, they would be [merge, edit] and not just [edit] (merge is a separate pending change indicator).